# Align in itemize

Tags: formatting, align, itemize

How could I achieve that the equations start in the same line than `first thing` and `second thing`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item first thing:
      \begin{align*}
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      c^2&=a^2+b^2
      \end{align*}
\item secong thing: 
      \begin{align*}
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      c^2&=a^2+b^2
      \end{align*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want this slight improvement: with the `eqparbox` package, you can have the equations start at the sime point for all items.

Unrelated: the language options of of `babel`,  since version 3.10, should be loaded with the document class, to ensure that all language-dependent  files be aware of the main document language.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{eqparbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \eqmakebox[things][l]{first thing: }
     $ \begin{aligned}[t]
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      c^2&=a^2+b^2
      \end{aligned} $
\item \eqmakebox[things][l]{second thing: }
     $ \begin{aligned}[t]
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      c^2&=a^2+b^2
      \end{aligned} $
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\displaystyle\begin{aligned}[t]
      \text{first thing: } c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
                           c^2&=a^2+b^2
      \end{aligned}$
\item $\displaystyle\begin{aligned}[t]
      \text{secong thing: } c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
                            c^2&=a^2+b^2
      \end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item first thing: $
      \begin{aligned}[t]
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      c^2&=a^2+b^2
      \end{aligned}$
\item secong thing: $
      \begin{aligned}[t]
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      c^2&=a^2+b^2
      \end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses environment `aligned` in inline math instead of the unnumbered display environment `align*`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item First thing:\\[.5ex]
      $\displaystyle\begin{aligned}
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      c^2&=a^2+b^2,
      \end{aligned}$\\
      where $c$ is real.
\item Second thing:\\[.5ex]
      $\displaystyle\begin{aligned}
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\text{, where $c$ is real.}
      \end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or if the first equation line should be in the text line the optional argument `[t]` helps:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item First thing:
      $\begin{aligned}[t]
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      c^2&=a^2+b^2
      \end{aligned}$
\item Second thing:
      $\begin{aligned}[t]
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      c^2&=a^2+b^2
      \end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: That's look good. What if I want to add a text in the first point after the last equation like `where $c$ is real.`?

Comment: Why `displaystyle`?

Comment: @Sigur The OP had used a math environment `align` that uses `\displaystyle`. As compromise, I kept it in the first example and removed it in the second.